# Can I get LinkedIn public available statistics of company pages without being an administrator?

Tags: analytics, linkedin-api

For my thesis I need publicly available statistics (#likes and #comments) of updates on LinkedIn company pages. However, the API requires you to be a company administrator. I only need publicly available statistics... 
Does anybody know how to get this data without having to count this manually?